# how to get string between 2 strings and the last string being ampersand using regex

Tags: regex, posix

I would like to extract `Wild%20Wolf` from game title and `50` from denomamount from this string using regex.

My product supports *"POSIX Extended Regular Syntax (ERE)"* and *"Perl backslash-sequences"*.

Thanks in advance!

(denomamount=).*?& gets everything like

> "denomamount=50&showInitialCashier=false&denomid=3311&minbet=50&parametersFromConfigCall=true&nscode=DDI&securetoken=dummyToken&xtautopull"

....

> "/tc/play?&countrycode=US&skincode=DDI-SKIN1&istournament=false&terminalid=&gametitle=**Wild%20Wolf**&buildnumber=R370.D1.0.F.CL79775_244&audio=on&uniqueid=11906989&defaultbuyinamount=1000.0&denomamount=**50**&showInitialCashier=false&denomid=3311&minbet=50&parametersFromConfigCall=true&nscode=DDI&securetoken=dummyToken&xtautopull"

Comment: Please correct the format.its not all understandable

Comment: so basically I need like anything between "&denomamount=" and the immediate "&"(ampersand)

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/19

Answer (score 0):

Through sed which uses Basic regular expression(BRE),

```
$ sed 's/.*gametitle=\([^&]*\).*denomamount=\([^&]*\).*/\1\n\2/g' file
Wild%20Wolf
50
```